# How to construct a complicated distance function?

Tags: real-analysis

As we know,a circle of radius $r$ centered at $(a,b)$. $f(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}-r$ is a distance function, An ellipse centered at $(a,b)$ $f(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{(x-a)^2}A+\frac{(y-b)^2}B}-r$ is also a distance function, but these curve is too simple, can we construct a distance function of a more complex curve?

Comment: What do you mean by a "distance function"?  Just a function whose value is zero on the curve and nonzero elsewhere?

Comment: The wiki gives a descripsion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function

Comment: Then I don't think your example for the ellipse is correct… the distance from a point to an ellipse cannot be expressed so simply.

Comment: I think what you're asking is "How can we calculate the distance of a point from an arbitrary curve?". I doubt there is any general answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than an answer, but ...

I found out over thirty years ago
that I could do a very good job 
of fitting a circle to a set of data points
in the plane
by minimizing
$\sum \left((x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2-r^2\right)$
instead of
$\sum \left(\sqrt{(x_i-a)^2+(y_i-b)^2}-r\right)$.

Since this is
$\sum \left(x_i^2-2x_ia+a^2+y_i^2-2y_ib+b^2-r^2\right)$,
by writing
$c = a^2+b^2-r^2$,
this becomes
$\sum \left(x_i^2-2x_ia+y_i^2-2y_ib+c\right)$,
which is *linear* in $a, b,$ and $c$,
and can thus be readily minimized.
$r$ can then be recovered from $a, b,$ and $c$.

Three notes on this:

1. The results are more accurate if the
   means of $x_i$ and $y_i$
   are subtracted from each
   before the minimization.
2. If you want to do the
   more exact fitting,
   this provides a good initial set of parameters
   to a nonlinear minimization routine.
3. This method generalizes very nicely
   to higher dimensions.